# What are the characteristics of a fusely beer?

Tags: fermentation, fermentation-temperature

I have heard that too warm a fermentation createds "fusely" beer. What are they and how can I tell if I have this problem?

Comment: fusely = containing [fusel alcohol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusel_alcohol), though I don't really know what that is or where it comes from